# Where is "curl.lib" for DMD?

Tags: curl, linker, d

When I `import etc.c.curl;` DMD tells me

```
Warning 2: File Not Found curl.lib
```

Where is this curl.lib?

(I've tried several packages from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html but haven't found curl.lib there. MSVC package `libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc.zip` have a `curllib.lib` but DMD won't link with it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create curl.lib using [implib](http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/implib.html). Implib is in the [Basic Utilities download](http://www.digitalmars.com/download/freecompiler.html).

Run it against your curllib.dll in /libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc/lib/Release/ like this:

```
implib /s curl.lib curllib.dll
```

Then put curl.lib where dmd can find it and compile. Unfortunately, you'll probably still get an [error about a missing libsasl.dll](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2009-04/0387.html) when you run your program. You may be able to use a [binary from Shining Light Productions](http://www.shininglightpro.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), build it with MSVC from the [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) source, or hunt it down online.

There's still a possibility you'll have trouble with conflicting versions. If you browse the etc.c.curl source, you'll notice it lists its cURL version as 7.21.4, which doesn't match any of the Windows binaries available. If you want something very reliable, you may have to wait for the next D cURL module or build everything yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I had no problems with "libsasl.dll" while using dlls from "Win32 - Generic" 7.22.0 libcurl at http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not there yet because Curl support in D is a work in progress.  `etc.c.curl` was added to Phobos with the intention of an object oriented wrapper eventually being added.  This wrapper has been through a round of review and is being revised in preparation for another round.  curl.lib will probably be included, at least on Windows, when Curl support is fully fleshed out and this wrapper is included.

Comment: I know about the review but from what i heard curl.lib inclusion is a separate matter. I actually agree that curl.lib shouldn't be included, instead it should be generated by the build tool from the fresh CURL. Also, curl.lib creation should be docummented in etc.c.curl.