# How to get std.net.curl to compile

Tags: d

If I try to compile a sample code from std.net.curl

```
import std.net.curl;

void main() {
    auto smtp = SMTP("smtps://smtp.gmail.com");
    smtp.setAuthentication("from.addr@gmail.com", "password");
    smtp.mailTo = ["<to.addr@gmail.com>"];
    smtp.mailFrom = "<from.addr@gmail.com>";
    smtp.message = "Example Message";
    smtp.perform();
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
OPTLINK (R) for Win32  Release 8.00.12
Copyright (C) Digital Mars 1989-2010  All rights reserved.
http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/optlink.html
curl.lib
 Warning 2: File Not Found curl.lib
test.obj(test)
(...)
--- errorlevel 8
```

I've been to http://curl.haxx.se/ but I don't know what exactly to do with the many files it has. I don't see curl.lib anywhere.

**Edit** Here's what I did to get it to work

- downloaded "Win32 - Generic" zip from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html
- downloaded "Basic utilities" from
  http://www.digitalmars.com/download/freecompiler.html
- ran "implib /s curl.lib libcurl.dll"
- put curl.lib in dmd2/windows/lib folder
- put libeay32.dll and ssleay.dll in dmd2/windows/bin folder

Everything seems to beworking OK now, although I don't have to link with curl.lib when compiling.

Comment: I think you might need to build the curl.lib

Comment: Ah yes, you don't have to link explicitly because the std.net.curl file includes this cool line: pragma(lib, "curl");, which does it automatically. And since you put the .lib straight in the lib folder, the linker had no trouble finding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this question should help:

[Where is "curl.lib" for DMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933845/where-is-curl-lib-for-dmd/7937155#7937155)

When you compile your app, you need to add curl.lib to the command line, and that question asks how to build curl.lib.

Answer (score 4):

[dmd's download page](http://dlang.org/download) contains a link to dmd compatible curl, so you can download and install curl from there. Then you need to link in curl.lib when compiling with dmd.

Comment: The link is dead, I'm afraid

Comment: @fwend Then that's worthy of a bug report: http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=9388